# Modular Monolith and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am currently struggling with dependency registration in my modular monolith with an ASP.NET Core 7 API.

Each of the modules requires a blob storage service. For this blob storage service, I have an `IBlobStorage` interface:

```cs
public interface IBlobStorage
{
    void Save(string name, byte[] content);
    Task<byte[]> Read(string name);
    void Remove(string name);
}
```

There are many different implementations for the interface, depending on which blob storage should be targeted (e.g. Azure Storage Account, Google Cloud Storage, ...).

The specific implementations require some information in their constructors, such as `IOptions` with a connection string.

`IBlobStorage` and its implementations reside in a kind of utility project that is referenced by all of the modules.

Each module is responsible for registering its own dependencies. The reason for this is that I want to be able to extract each module into a separate deployable unit with as few changes as possible.

The crux of the matter is that it should be possible to configure each module to target a different Storage Account instance. This means that I need to be able to register an `IBlobStorage` implementation **per module**, and resolve the implementation with the correct options for the corresponding module (side-note: the ASP.NET controllers are also part of the modules they belong to; maybe that helps solve the problem).

I wish I could do this without the modules knowing anything about running in a monolith.

I'm currently playing around with Autofac as an alternative to the built-in DI container (in particular, the ability to register dependencies as `Keyed` sounds promising), but this seems like a lot of work and I wonder if there's an easier solution that I haven't seen yet.

Has anyone come across anything like this? I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction

---

**Update:** I created a minimal example to illustrate my problem: https://github.com/tnotheis/ModularMonolith

Run the `ModularMonolith` project and execute a GET request to https://localhost:7222/A and https://localhost:7222/B respectively.

The expected behavior is that /A returns "This is data for 'ModuleA'", while /B returns "This is data for 'ModuleB'.

Instead, both of them return "This is data for 'ModuleB'" because ModuleB is registered after ModuleA, which "overrides" the `IModuleSpecificService` registration.

Comment: I'm not familiar with autofac, but some DI containers are hierarchical, so you can have a global container for things common for all modules, and a sub-container each module, with registrations in each. The closest thing I can find in Autofac is "lifetime scope", but I don't think this is quite the same thing.

Comment: this sounds like you want to register a factor and the factory gets the type based off x... look into abstract factory and registering your types then in the consume it requests a type via the factor which was injecting which its types were injected in

Comment: i believe your wanting something like https://medium.com/null-exception/factory-pattern-using-built-in-dependency-injection-of-asp-net-core-f91bd3b58665
could be wrong

Comment: Your options are Autofac's keyed registrations, or building something on top of the default Microsoft DI that works like Autofac's keyed registrations. There's a good reason that the default DI doesn't support this.

Comment: This is [an FAQ in the Autofac docs.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 0):

> This means that I need to be able to register an IBlobStorage implementation per module

1. There is no "per module" scope in the Microsoft Extensions DI container.
2. So you want to rely on an *interface*, but the semantics of this interface vary per use thereof.

Therefore:

1. Change DI framework to one that has a module scope, or
2. Change DI framework to one that has named/keyed registrations, or
3. Create multiple containers, or
4. Use "marker interfaces" by using inheritance:

```cs
public interface IModuleABlobContainer : IBlobContainer {  }

services.AddScoped<IModuleABlobContainer>(new ModuleABlobContainer(options));
```

And then code agains that in Module A, because frankly, your `IBlobContainer` apparently isn't module-agnostic.

Comment: I thought about the "marker interfaces" solution as well, of course. But I discarded it because I would need a separate implementation of the marker interface for every single module and for every single supported cloud provider. I currently have 7 modules and support 2 cloud providers, which means there would be 7 interfaces and 14 classes. Plus there are other infrastructure classes with the same problem.
But all the other solutions are probably even worse. And since adding new modules is rather rare, and adding a cloud provider even rarer, I will probably go with this approach.

Comment: The point is that you rely on a specific implementation of the interface `IBlobContainer`, so it is impossible to register and use that interface. That goes beyond dependency injection, it's a design issue. If you have 7 modules with 2 module-specific blob storage providers, then you're going to need a way to discern between those 14. And as I understand it, they won't leak outside of their module.

Comment: Or you're going to have to redesign the `IBlobContainer` so it uses connection-specific information in its upload/download/list methods, instead of in its constructor.